# Why do correlation functions involving composite fields require special analysis?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, singularities, correlation-functions

For simplicity I will be considering $\phi^4$ theory. To analyze correlation functions of the form
$$\langle \phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\ldots\phi(x_n)$$
with
$$x_1 \neq x_2 \neq \cdots \neq x_n \tag{1}$$
we can use perturbation theory and the usual Feynman rules.

Now consider a correlation function where the condition (1) is dropped. That is, some of the fields may be located at the same spacetime location and are said to be composite fields, for example

$$\langle \phi^n(x_1) \phi(x_2)\phi(x_3). \tag{2}$$

My questions about these correlation functions are the following:

1. Why do correlation functions involving composite fields require special analysis and a new set of Feynman rules?
2. Why do they require new renormalizations?
3. How do composite fields introduce new divergences? Are these from the propagators, i.e. we have something like $D(x_1 - x_1)$?
4. Why is (2) seen as a 3-point function and not an $n+2$-point function?
5. Wouldn't the interaction term $\phi^4$ also be considered a composite fields?

I apologize for including multiple questions in one post but I thought most of them are too related to open separate questions. I have already taken a look at the following related question: [Aren't $\phi^4$ composite operators?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/150915/) but am still confused regarding the above.

Comment: The main problem is regarding how we choose to define $\phi^2(x)$. The standard definition $\phi^2 (x) = \phi(x) \phi(x)$ does not work.

Comment: @Prahar When I tried it I got a divergence coming from the propagator, something like $D(x_1 - x_1)$, and I assume this is why new renormalizations and Feynman rules are needed. Is that the problem you are referring to?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. Note that this is a problem even in free theories, it has nothing to do with interactions. Interactions just make this problem much worse.

Comment: @Prahar I see, thank you very much for your help!